# Can i change windows registry where wslvar username is stored?

Tags: windows-10, ubuntu, user-accounts, windows-subsystem-for-linux, user

After i renamed my user and its folder $(wslvar USERNAME) still returns old one need help how to change that registry key. I tried unchecking wsl in features and chacking back on but did not helped

Comment: You are best to get the data from  the user folder as it exists, store it in c:\temp. Make a new user name (member of admin) log in to the new account, delete the old user and profiles, make a new user for yourself and restore your data. Bad move to depend on the registry here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`wslvar USERNAME` is looking for the Windows environment variable named `USERNAME`, so according to [this comment](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cd35f292-616a-4622-96cb-19138a59d7e8/changing-username-variable?forum=win10itprogeneral) with the same situation (rename of user and folder, environment variable not updated), the answer is to:

- Run `netplwiz` in Windows
- Double-click the user account
- Correct the username there
- Log out the user and back in

I haven't tested this myself, of course, but it seems likely that this work, and it's easy enough to try.

Comment: thx that worked for me